# What is the behavior for the minus operator between two datetimes in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, datetime

The difference between to datetimes is the number of seconds between them. This seems to work only if the datetimes occur in the same hour.

Why is this?

```
mysql> update events set created_at = "2011-04-13 15:59:59", fulfilled_at ="2011-04-13 16:00:00" where id = 1;
mysql> select fulfilled_at - created_at, timediff(fulfilled_at, created_at) from events where id = 1;
+---------------------------+------------------------------------+
| fulfilled_at - created_at | timediff(fulfilled_at, created_at) |
+---------------------------+------------------------------------+
|               4041.000000 | 00:00:01                           |
+---------------------------+------------------------------------+
```

I know I should be using timediff, but I'm just curious why I'm seeing this or if it's documented somewhere.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

MySQL is just converting strings into numbers as best it can, so that it can do the mathematical operation on them.  In this case, its just stripping out all of the non numerical colons, dashes and spaces.

Try this:

```
SELECT (20110413155959 - 20110413160000) AS dates;
```

Your dates, without all the stuff that stops them being numbers - the result is **-4041**

Answer (score 6):

Recall that mysql has two differente kinds of datetime-related substractions: The **_SUB** suffix is for substracting **a date minus an interval**,  returning a **date**. The **_DIFF** suffix is for getting the **difference between two dates**, returning an **interval** (BTW, notice that only the first one has an inverse analog: **_ADD**)

The +/- signs are to be used for the first one (ADD/SUB), hence MYSQL expects an interval as a second argument.

```
DATE = DATE_ADD(DATE,INTERVAL)    Also accepts +
DATE = DATE_SUB(DATE,INTERVAL)    Also accepts -
INTERVAL = DATE_DIFF(DATE,DATE )
```

See doc [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add), the bit starting from:

```
Date arithmetic also can be performed using INTERVAL 
together with the + or - operator...
```

Hence, it's incorrect to use the - to take the difference between two dates. Now, MYSQL, when confronted with incorrect outputs, tries to do its best guess (instead of throwing an error), sometimes that goes well, sometimes not.

Comment: Poor MySQL, imagine your altimeter behaves incorrectly in your Boeing instead of failing miserably. Why it tries to convert to string, then do the best guess? Is it so PHP* developers can continue working on their website? *take it with a grain of salt